# How to have a different storage for development and production?

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

How do you even differentiate between the production and development environments in `react-native`?

Precisely, I would like to have a different storage when running my app in the Metro Bundler (development) and when running the application that is installed on my iPhone.

Is there a standard way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Targets in xcode with `.plist` file for each one. Product Flavors in android studio

Comment: I'm not too familiar with xcode. I create a new target in my project, then what?

Comment: Aren't the development App a different app then the production App?

Comment: Well my app isn't published on the App Store. It's simply installed/built with Xcode.